# How to expand and close the tr based on checbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

I have 10 rows in a table. Each row first column(td) is ( + button) for expansion of new tr rows. i can expand and close any row by click the + button manyally. but i also have one common check box to expand and close the all tr at a time. This is working fine when i am doing in separate. if i click the checkbox it will click the + button using code ( $(this).click() )

but the problem is i expanded one row by clicking + button. After that i am clicking the common checkbox then it will open all the expanded row, but here it closing the row which i opened already. my requirement don't close the rows already opened by clicking the + button.

At the time of expand i am adding a new class (".shown") to the current row(tr) in which i clicked.and the + button class name is (" .details-control ").

The below code is for common checkbox code at time of click.

```
$('.common-checkall').on('change', function() {
    var status = this.checked; 
    $(".details-control:visible").each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
});
```

This is the code for + button expand

```
$(elemId+' tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = royaltiesTable.row(tr);
    try {
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            row.child(format(row.data(), tr)).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us your working code. So that we can able to solve your query.

Comment: i have added this code only.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a checking before calling
`$(this).click();`
e.g.

```
$('.common-checkall').on('change', function() {
    var status = this.checked; 
    $(".details-control:visible").each(function(){    
        if((status && !$(this).hasClass('shown')) || (!status && $(this).hasClass('shown'))) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});
```